# Json parsing errors

Tags: php, json

I've got the following JSON and PHP and i'm i'm getting errors and I can't see what i've done wrong

**Error**

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Users\tom.AD\PhpstormProjects\SYS\index.php on line 7

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Users\tom.AD\PhpstormProjects\SYS\index.php on line 9

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Users\tom.AD\PhpstormProjects\SYS\index.php on line 11
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "apr": [
    {
      "f1": "139eg1",
      "zones": [
        {
          "f2": "unknown",
          "zone": "123"
        },
        {
          "f2": "unknown",
          "zone": "321"
        },
        {
          "f2": "unknown",
          "zone": "123"
        },
        {
          "f2": "top",
          "zone": "321"
        },
        {
          "f2": "unknown",
          "zone": "123"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "f1": "139eg2",
      "zones": [
        {
          "f2": "unknown",
          "zone": "123"
        },
        {
          "f2": "unknown",
          "zone": "321"
        },
        {
          "f2": "unknown",
          "zone": "123"
        },
        {
          "f2": "top",
          "zone": "321"
        },
        {
          "f2": "unknown",
          "zone": "123"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "f1": "139eg3",
      "zones": [
        {
          "f2": "unknown",
          "zone": "123"
        },
        {
          "f2": "unknown",
          "zone": "321"
        },
        {
          "f2": "unknown",
          "zone": "123"
        },
        {
          "f2": "top",
          "zone": "321"
        },
        {
          "f2": "unknown",
          "zone": "123"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**PHP**

```
$json_file = file_get_contents('json/posts.json');

$jfo = json_decode($json_file);

$title = $jfo->apr->f1;

$posts = $jfo->apr->zones;

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->zone;
}
```

Comment: Assuming line 7 is `$title = $jfo->apr->f1;` then clearly `$jfo` does not contain what you think it does.  Without more information from you, i.e. what have you done to verify things up to that point, nobody can really help you.

Answer (score 1):

`apr` is an array of objects, thus cannot be accessed with `->`, according to your `JSON` you have supplied us. It seems you want to access all the zones. To do that, you would need to loop through the array with something like:

```
foreach ($jfo->apr as $object) {
    print_r($object->zones);
}
```

To access them directly (since you have no keys and it is an indexed array), you'd need to do `$jfo->apr[$key]` where key is some numeric value that is an existing index in the array `$jfo->apr`. For example:

```
$first_zone_array = $jfo->apr[0]; //This gets the following:
object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["f1"]=> string(6) "139eg1" ["zones"]=> array(5) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["f2"]=> string(7) "unknown" ["zone"]=> string(3) "123" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#4 (2) { ["f2"]=> string(7) "unknown" ["zone"]=> string(3) "321" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["f2"]=> string(7) "unknown" ["zone"]=> string(3) "123" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { ["f2"]=> string(3) "top" ["zone"]=> string(3) "321" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2) { ["f2"]=> string(7) "unknown" ["zone"]=> string(3) "123" } } }
```